# Noise Applied to OFDM Subcarriers

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, ofdm

Assume we have an OFDM signal received with AWGN + phase noise. Then, we extracted some subcarriers after the demodulation. Now each subcarrier $Y_l[k]$ includes a noise component $Z_l[k]$ according to this equation:

$$ Y_l[k] = H_l[k] X_l[k] + Z_l[k] $$

My question is: are the noise components of each subcarrier dependent or independent on each other?
In other words, does  $Z_l[k+1]$ depend on  $Z_l[k]$?
Also, is there any relationship between the noise and the frequency of the subcarrier?

Comment: The phase noise on each subcarrier could be correlated if introduced in a common frequency translation operation. Are you able to extract the noise only (by testing with a known signal) and then cross-correlate the noise only terms?

Comment: No, I can extract the subcarrier with the noise. It will be difficult to extract the noises separately since I am working on USRP implementation.  If I were able to extract the noises only, then it is easy to know if they are correlated or not. I have one more question please, If I applied filtering to some subcarriers separately , then can I make the noises independent?

Comment: If you can send the same data on each subcarrier- and have an independent measurement or knowledge of what the SNR is on each subcarrier (which you can get from an EVM measurement) then you can compare that to the cross correlation to extract how dependent the noise term is. I can’t think of filtering you can do on the received signal to make the noise independent but not affect the signal

Comment: Thanks! 
I will try that.